# Edge weight changing during execution in shortest path algorithm

Tags: algorithms, graphs, shortest-path

I have an undirected graph with weighted edges, in which I want to find the shortest paths from an initial node to every other node. Obviously [Dijkstra's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra's_algorithm) is usually a good choice, and I have previously used the variant where a min-priority queue (heap) is used to keep the set of tentative nodes $N_T$, and nodes are only added to $N_T$ as they are discovered.

However in this problem edge weights are dynamic. Each edge has a weight $w_{ab}=d_{ab}\gamma_b$, where $d_{ab}$ is the constant distance between nodes $a$ and $b$, and $\gamma_b$ is a dynamic scaling factor. $\gamma$ is first defined when a node is added to the tentative set, and it is fixed when a node is marked as visited. But while a node remains in the tentative set, $\gamma$ can change depending on the nodes visited *in other parts of the graph*. These non-local changes make it difficult to maintain the queue, since an addition of a new node may cause the weights to change and require the whole queue to be re-sorted.

If it helps: the tentative nodes are in groups, and nodes within a group will change weights uniformly - although groups can sometimes split and merge. So in fact the edge weight is $w_{ab}=d_{ab}\gamma_g$, where $g$ is the tentative node's group.

[image]
*Illustration of groups during graph traversal from node $n_0$. At first there are two $\gamma$ groups, $g_x$ and $g_y$. Later, they merge into one group, $g_z$. $\gamma$ is constant within each coloured rectangle. The dashed lines show the tentative node set at various times during execution.*

**What is the most efficient way to  manage the group of tentative nodes**, given that the edge weights may change? I am open to other ways to tackle the problem, e.g. run Dijkstra's algorithm in multiple passes, only updating $\gamma$ after each pass.

In terms of problem size, the graph is sparse and there are on the order of:

- $\lvert{N}\rvert\approx100k$ nodes
- $\lvert{N_T}\rvert\approx1000$ nodes in the tentative set
- $\lvert{G}\rvert<\lvert{N_T}\rvert$ $\gamma$ groups